# How to bind multiple objects to a collection?

Tags: c#, angularjs

Angular Newb, trying to make a simple checklist app and understand relationships.  The user can add a list of items.  My ItemList class has a title, date and a collection of items.  My Item class has item names and quantities.  How can I use input boxes with ng-model multiple times?

Here's my ItemList.cs

```
namespace BringIt.Models {
    public class ItemList {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }

    }
}
```

and Item.cs

```
namespace BringIt.Models {
    public class Item {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public int ItemQty { get; set; }
        public string Person { get; set; }
        public ItemList ItemList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my basic form

```
<form ng-submit="controller.save()">
   Title <input ng-model="controller.itemList.title" />
   Item Name <input ng-model="controller.item.itemName"/>
   Quantity <input ng-model="controller.item.itemQty" />.

   //would like to do it again for more items
   Item Name 2 <input ng-model="controller.item.itemName" />
   Quantity 2 <input ng-model="controller.item.itemQty" />


    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

When I run the code and type something into the first model, it instantly shows in the second matching input box.  I ultimately want to allow the user to add as many items as they would like, and the collection would just keep increasing.  Also, any other suggestions for best practices I may be missing are always helpful.

I've now got the following code, which almost works, but doesn't add new spaces for more objects after I fill in the first one.

```
 public addNew() {
        debugger;
        this.items = []
        var item = {itemName: "default name", itemQty: "default qty"}; // you can set default values here
        this.items.push(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate with `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    Item Name {{$index}} <input ng-model="item.itemName" />
    Quantity {{$index}} <input ng-model="item.itemQty" />
</div>
<button ng-click="addNew()"></button>
```

Add new item:

```
$scope.items = [{
    itemName: 'existing item name',
    itemQty: 'existing item quantity'
}];

$scope.addNew = function () {
    var item = {}; // you can set default values here
    items.push(item);
};
```

Comment: cool, thanks, I thought I could only use the repeat to display my objects, not accept them.

Comment: Can anyone help me do this in Typescript using the controller As syntax?  I'm lost in the $scope world.  As hard as I try, I can't get it to work quite right.

Comment: just use `this` instead of `$scope` and change `items` with `vm.items` where vm  is controller as name.

Comment: I'm close, but it isn't quite that simple. I've added my latest attempt to the bottom of the original post.